# $\#$P hardness of computing weighted sum of degree $2$ polynomials

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity, approximation-hardness, polynomials, finite-fields

Consider polynomials $f: \{0, 1\}^{n} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (addition and multiplication are taken modulo $2$.) Consider integers $x \in \{0,1\}^{n}$, written in binary. Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of all integers.

Define
\begin{align}
\mathrm{gap}(f) &= \sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}} (-1)^{f(x)} \\
&= |\{x : f(x) = 0\}| - |\{x : f(x) = 1\}|.
\end{align}

According to [this](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.44.9881&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper, and [this](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ecsxam/papers/lowdegree.pdf) paper (Proposition $6$), we know two things about $\mathrm{gap}(f)$:

1. It is (in the worst case) #P-hard to exactly compute $|\{x : f(x) = 0\}|$, and hence, $\mathrm{gap}(f)$, when $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $3$.
2. $|\{x : f(x) = 0\}|$ and $\mathrm{gap}(f)$ can be computed in polynomial time when $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$.

---

Now, define a new quantity
\begin{align}
\mathrm{weightedgap}(f) &= \sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}} w_{x} (-1)^{f(x)},~\text{where}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
w =(w_0, w_1, \ldots, w_{2^{n}-1}) ~\text{is some fixed weight function such that}\\~~w_i \neq w_j~~\text{for}~i \neq j~~\text{and}~~\text{each}~~w_i\in \mathbb{Z}~~\text{where}~~i, j \in \{0, 1\}^{n}.
\end{align}

Let $f$ be a degree $2$ polynomial.

I have two related questions:

1. For every choice of such a weight function (which is known
   beforehand and which satisfies the constraints mentioned), what is the worst-case hardness of
   exactly computing this quantity?
2. For every choice of such a weight function (which is known
   beforehand and which satisfies the constraints mentioned), what is the worst-case hardness of
   approximating this quantity, upto an inverse polynomial multiplicative error?

Note that we have only one input here --- an efficient description of the degree $2$ function $f$. The weight function is not a part of the input.

---

I think both my computations are #P-hard. But I could not do a formal reduction.

Note that, unlike in the unweighted version, computing $|\{x : f(x) = 0\}|$ does not allow us to compute $\mathrm{weightedgap}(f)$: we need to look at the actual values of the function in $\mathcal{O}(2^{n})$ places. So, I think it is very unlikely that we can do this in polynomial time.

EDIT $1$: [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06386.pdf) paper talks of #P-hardness of computing general weighted sums, but nothing specifically for degree $2$ polynomials.

EDIT $2$: Theorem $9$ of [this](https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/%7Eabulatov/papers/weightedcsp.pdf) paper seems close to what we need. Maybe some close variant of Theorem $9$ is sufficient?

Comment: The complexity of your problem highly depends on how $w_x$ are given in the input. If they are given explicitly as a list, your input being of size $O(2^n)$, you can obviously solve it in polynomial time.

Comment: @holf I don't think $w$ is part of the input. So the question if whether there is a $w$ for which the problem is #P-hard.

Comment: ok thanks. This reminds me of #XOR-SAT (clauses are sums modulo $2$ of literals) being in $P$ while the weighted version (weights on literal) is #P-complete. I will look for the reference later and see if it is good enough for an answer.

Comment: @holf Thanks! That will be very helpful. :)

Comment: I found this paper (https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/~abulatov/papers/weightedcsp.pdf) and I wonder if Theorem 9 of this paper can be applied to solve the problem. I could not work out the full details but it seemed close to what we need for this.

Comment: This is the paper I had in mind but have not checked yet. I should have more time next week but if you have time before to figure it out, I would be glad to read your answer ;).